# Can't generate another debug keystore error : Missing keystore

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, keystore

I'm trying to generate another debug keystore for my app, I have created a dev keystore and assigned the store file inside .android and with the name dev.keystore, then I assigned this new keystore to my debug build variant

[image]

Then asigned this dev key to the debug build variant

[image]

But when I try to get the sha1 of this key this happens

[image]

I have been all day long trying to generate a new sha1 key with this and I cant

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Show your `build.gradle` file

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: did you manage to find smth ?